# Why changes in .scss file are transformed into .css file

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass

scss file which contains following class which basically changes the font size.

```
 .verticaltab
    {
    font-size:11px;
    }
```

and following is the Test.css file contains the same class

```
.vertcaltab
{
font-size:14px;
}
```

so should changes in .scss file (font change) overwrite or transform the changes in .css file.
I am not able to see any font change on UI after making change on .scss file.

But when I make change in .css file I am able to see the font size change.

So what exactly .scss file do? and why I must make changes in .scss file but I am not able to see the changes in UI?

Comment: The changes which get reflected on UI are follows  in Test.css    .verticaltab
    {
    font-size:11px;
    } . So any need to make changes in Test.scss file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Test.css file would be the last entry in your page. Change the order of CSS inclusion to HTML page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Changes were not happening because I did not install "Mindscape web workbench" extension in visual studio.